# Spring Testing Unsatisfied depencency NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-test

When I try to run my tests they all fail becaouse they can't find the bean of one of my classes.

Here are my codes which are used in the context:

The exception I get is this:

```
Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'testProtoAdminController' : Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 2; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'TestProtoCopyService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

**TestProtoAdminControllerTest**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers = TestProtoAdminController.class)
public class TestProtoAdminControllerTest {

//Some used services

 @Before
public void setUp() {
    authenticatedMockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
}

@Test
@WithMockUser
public void testCopyProto() throws Exception {
    authenticatedMockMvc.perform(post("/api/admin/{id}/copy", 1)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .content(asJson(new TestProtoBaseVo()))).andExpect(status().isOk());
}

//Some more tests which are not important in this case
```

**TestProtoCopyService**

```
@Service
public class TestProtoCopyServiceImpl implements TestProtoCopyService {

    //Other services and repositories I have to use.
    //Methods

}
```

**TestProtoCopyService**

```
public interface TestProtoCopyService {
    @Transactional
    void copyTestProto(long testProtoId, String sourceTenant, String targetTenant);
}
```

**TestProtoAdminController**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/*")
public class TestProtoAdminController {
private TestProtoCopyService testProtoCopyService;

public TestProtoAdminController(TestProtoCopyService testProtoCopyService {
    this.testProtoCopyService = testProtoCopyService;
}
```

Comment: Please do include the exception in your question, not in a link on pastbin. That will help others, once the pastebin entry is offline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `@WebMvcTest` Spring will prepare everything to test your web layer. This doesn't mean all your beans are scanned and are part of this test application context and ready to inject.

In general, you usually mock the service class of your controller with `@MockBean` and then use Mockito to specify its behavoir:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers = TestProtoAdminController.class)
public class TestProtoAdminControllerTest {

  @MockBean
  private TestProtoCopyService mockedService

  // the rest

  @Before
  public void setUp() {
    authenticatedMockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
  }

  @Test
  @WithMockUser
  public void testCopyProto() throws Exception {

    authenticatedMockMvc.perform(post("/api/admin/{id}/copy", 1)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .content(asJson(new TestProtoBaseVo()))).andExpect(status().isOk());
  }
```

If you want Spring Boot to bootstrap the whole application context with every bean consider using `@SpringBootTest`. With this annotation, you can inject any bean to your application. The downside here is that you need to provide the whole infrastructure (database/queues/etc.) for your test.

Comment: This was the problem I forgot to add the mockbean to my test. Thank you for the help! :D